# Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{10}2^x}{e^x}$ exists and is finite

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{10}2^x}{e^x}$ exists and is finite.

I have tried applying L'Hôpital's rule repeatedly, with no success. I cannot see a pattern or a way to simplify nicely.

I can obviously see that this integral evaluates to $0$, but have found no way to show it. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

From a single step of L'Hôpital's rule, notice that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{10}}{\left( \frac{e}{2}\right)^x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10x^{9}}{\ln\left( \frac{e}2\right)\left( \frac{e}{2}\right)^x}$$

Notice that the power of of the numerator reduces by $1$ and but the denominator form doesn't change much. What happens if you do it twice? what happens if you do it $10$ times?

Answer (score 1):

Another option: for $k,\,n>0$, $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-kx}=\frac{n!}{k^{n+1}}$ is finite, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^n e^{-kx}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{x^{10}2^x}{e^x} 
  = \dfrac{x^{10}e^{x \log 2}}{e^x}
  = \dfrac{x^{10}}{e^{(1-\log 2)x}}
  = \dfrac{x^{10}}{e^{Kx}}$

Where  $K = 1-\log 2 > 0$.

It shouldn't be too much trouble to show that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\displaystyle \lim e^{\log{\frac{x^{10}2^{x}}{e^{x}}}}$ , which equivalent to $e^{\lim (10\log{x} + x\log 2 - x)}$, so $\lim -x(\frac{10 \log{x}}{x} + (1-\log{2})) \to -\infty$, so you have $\lim e^{\dots} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{x^{10}2^{x}}{e^{x}}) = \lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{x^{10}}{(\frac{e^{x}}{2^{x}})})$

Then use L'hopital here

Answer (score 0):

The tenth root of the function is

$$xa^{-x}$$ where $a:=\sqrt[10]{\dfrac e2}>1.$

If you increase $x$ by $1$, this amounts to multiplying that expression by

$$c(x):=\frac{x+1}{ax}.$$

For $x>32.091\cdots$, this factor becomes smaller than $1$ so that the function can be bounded by a decreasing geometric sequence.